# Is there a way to add an empty entry to a Legend in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, legend

I wanted to add a blank space to a legend in a matplotib plot in python. I have an odd number of entries in the legend, and it currently looks like:

```
 _________________________________________________________________
|  handle1  -  label1   handle3  -  label3   handle5  -  label5  |
|  handle2  -  label2   handle4  -  label4                       |
```

However, the data is logically grouped in pairs with a control, so it would be better if it looked like this:

```
 _________________________________________________________________
|  handle1  -  label1   handle2  -  label2   handle4  -  label4  |
|                       handle3  -  label3   handle5  -  label5  |
```

The legend is being generated during automatically running a for loop over the data set:

```
for [folder1,folder2, label] in folder_list:
    parse_folder([folder1,folder2])
    color = next(colorgen)
    marker = next(markergen)
    ax1.errorbar(percent[0],percent[1], yerr=per_std, c=color, fmt=marker, label=label)
    if label == 'Flat Plate':
        print 'tripped'
        ax1.plot(np.NaN, np.NaN, '-', color='none', label=' ')
```

and then at the end calling

```
leg = ax1.legend(loc='lower left',fancybox=True,prop={'size':fontsize-2},ncol=4,bbox_to_anchor=(-0.1, -0.315))
```

Is there a way to insert this blank spot into the legend?

Comment: A more complete example code--how to get the legend you don't want, or including things you've tried--would be helfpul. Have you tried `ax1.plot(np.NaN, np.NaN, '-', color='none', label='')`?

Comment: That almost works except for some reason the blank spot that creates is always the first thing on the legend, no matter here I put the plot command. Everything else is in order of call.

Comment: If you hang onto the line handles you could force the ordering. Again, a more complete example would be helpful.

Comment: The lines are being plotted inside a for loop, so hanging onto the handles is not an option.

Comment: That something is being plotted inside a loop doesn't mean you can't hang on to handles any more than that something is being calculated in a loop means you can't build a list of the results.

Comment: Apparently the problem is that the legend generator gets different plot types sequentially, ie all `plot`, then all `errorbar`, etc., so the blank entry needs to be the same type to stay in order: `ax1.errorbar(np.NaN, np.NaN, yerr=np.NaN, fmt= '-', c='w', label=' ')`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Farenorth's solution (given in the comments to the Op) give the cleanest answer.

Add an additional command in the position that you need the blank spot, using `np.NaN` for data and setting the color to `none`.

```
ax1.plot(np.NaN, np.NaN, '-', color='none', label='')
```

Note that this must be of the same type, as the method used to automatically generate the Legend gets different plot types sequentially, ie all plot, then all errorbar, etc., so the blank entry needs to be the same type to stay in order of the function calls.

Comment: This didn't work for me unless I changed the label to have a space: `" "`

Comment: This didn't work for me with or without the space. But @remi-cuingnet 's answer did work (matplotlib.lines.Line2D([], [], color="none")).

Answer (score 11):

You can define a fake white line

```
l = Line2D([0],[0],color="w")
```

Then plot your data and save the line/markers in variables

```
f = figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111)

l1, = ax.plot(1*arange(10))
l2, = ax.plot(2*arange(10))
l3, = ax.plot(3*arange(10))
l4, = ax.plot(4*arange(10))
l5, = ax.plot(5*arange(10))
```

Finally, you call `legend` as follows

```
ax.legend((l1,l,l2,l3,l4,l5),("label1","","label2","label3","label4","label5"),
           loc='upper center',fancybox=True,ncol=3)
```

where for each line/marker is associated with a different label. At the place where you want to have a gap in your legend insert the fake white line `l` and associate a blank string to it.

Hope it helps.[image]

Comment: I would rather use `matplotlib.lines.Line2D([], [], color="none")` for the empty line.